# wpf binding with different source and target

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, .net-4.0

Is is possible to make a binding in WPF whereas the source and target are different properties.

A la something like

> Binding="{Binding Source=MySourceProperty, Target=MyTargetProperty}"

**As requested an explanation of what I need to do:**
The program among other things allows editing of properties that are part of a primary key in the database. If the property just gets changed, then this will either not update the DB value or create a duplicate, depending on how I handle saving the object. A different target would allow this to work (by explicitly specifying what to update by using the 'old' value).

Comment: **what??** (this text exists just to meet the minimum comment length)

Comment: can you be more detailed in your question?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There's no practical context where you will want that. What do really you need to do?

Comment: Well I guess you missunderstand the idea of binding. It's not for pipelining values between properties. Well at least not in the way you're trying it. ;o)

Comment: Can you brief on objective behind having such functionality? Do you want to maintain some kind of dictionary to know the source and bound target?

Comment: `A different target would allow this to work` - I think you have a really bad misconception of the Binding mechanics. WPF doesn't care about your database. You need to create a proper ViewModel to manipulate that.

Comment: @HighCore Can you elaborate a bit on how you would structure 'a proper VM' in this case?

Comment: @user1151923 I have no idea dude. Post some sample code and XAML of what you need and I can tell you.

Comment: I don't think you can name the target and source different properties.   In the Set is where you should handle that logic.  You can reject the value in the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Binding` defined in XAML is always targeting the object and property on which it's defined.

If you define the `Binding` [*in code*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx), you can/must specify the source and target explicitly.  This is, essentially, how the `Binding`  class works:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("SourceProperty"); // Sets up the source property
myBinding.Source = mySourceObject; // sets up the source object
targetProperty.SetBinding(TargetType.TargetDepProperty, binding); // This sets the target object/binding
```

The XAML markup extension for a binding takes care of setting up the target side of the equation automatically, so it's always the object on which you define the binding.

Answer (score 0):

In the set of the public property you have access to the old value
key is the old value
value is the proposed value from the binding
you can reject the value that comes from the binding

```
private string key;

public string Key 
{
   get { return key; }
   set 
   {
       if (key == value) return;
       // try data update 
       bool success = updateDB();
       if (success) key = value;  // only update if success
   }
}
```

I would combine the above with validation to notify the user if a value was invalid.
[Validation Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer WHAT you need instead of asked incorrect HOW

> "If the property just gets changed, then this will either not update
>   the DB value or create a duplicate"

In your property `set`ter you should check `set { if (this.someMember != value)` if the typed in value is has changed:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private string someMember;
public int SomeProperty 
{
    get 
    { return this.someMember; }
    set 
    {
       if (this.someMember != value)
       {
           someMember = value;
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
           {
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SomeProperty"));
           }
     }
}
```

**As aside-note (or off-topic),**
you might find useful the codeproject [DataContext in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321899/DataContext-in-WPF) article in its last [Download the source code](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=38ecce05b21b8b44&id=38ECCE05B21B8B44!403) has a sample when updates of one VisualModel's property is reflected (synchronized with updates in the other VM's property)

Immediately after launch:

[image]

The text typed in the 1st textbox is reflected in the 2nd textbox and vice versa, the text typed in the 2nd textbox is reflected in the 1st.

[image]

The text typed in the 3d textbox is reflected in the 4th textbox (and in textblock content at bottom) and vice versa, the text typed in the 4th textbox is reflected in the 3d (and in textblock content at bottom) .

[image]

Note that the download is `DataCotext Inner Objects.zip` which is unzipped into  directory and solution with name `Bindingtoclassesstate`